# How to use multiple useInput in a component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, nextui

Introduction:
I'm new to web development, I come from mobile. I have two Textareas in a page to build a text article, which I need to reset after submit.

Problem:

```
import { useInput } from "@nextui-org/react"
const {
  value: controlledValue,
  setValue: setControlledValue,
  reset,
  bindings,
} = useInput("");

const {
  value: controlledValue,
  setValue: setControlledValue,
  reset,
  bindings,
} = useInput("")
```

I'm trying to use two useInputs hooks, one for the article title and the second for the article body. I have tried many ways to reset the Texture but I can't. I see that with this hook "useInput" it works.
The problem is that I can't rename the values of that hook and then they are duplicated.

Please is there a way to use this hook for multiple values?

I'm on NextJS 13.0 / NextUI and using TypeScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rename values returned from the hook as follows:

```js
"use client";

import * as React from "react";
import { useInput } from "@nextui-org/react";

export default function Home() {
  const { reset: reset1, bindings: bindings1 } = useInput("");
  const { reset: reset2, bindings: bindings2 } = useInput("");

  const onSubmit = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const data = new FormData(event.target as HTMLFormElement);

    const textarea1 = data.get("textarea1");
    const textarea2 = data.get("textarea2");

    // ...

    reset1();
    reset2();
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      <textarea name="textarea1" {...bindings1} />
      <textarea name="textarea2" {...bindings2} />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Comment: love you man...